# Update dataframe based on match in another dataframe if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I want to update the first one.
df1 contains different Markets (M1, M2, etc.) and some Codes for each of them (numbers or Dummy)

```
import pandas as pd
labels = ["Market","Code"]
values = [["M1","1234"],["M1","Dummy"],["M1","1234"],["M2","Dummy"],["M1","1234"]]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values,columns=labels)
print(df)
 Market   Code
0     M1   1234
1     M1  Dummy
2     M1   1234
3     M2  Dummy
4     M1   1234
```

If Code == Dummy, then I want to update the Code in df based on the value in df2 for this specific market. So each Market should receive a different new Code.

```
labels = ["Market","Code(New)"]
values = [["M1","4567"],["M2","5678"]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values,columns=labels)
print(df2)
 Market Code(New)
0     M1      4567
1     M2      5678
```

in the end I should get

```
labels = ["Market","Code"]
values = [["M1","1234"],["M1","4567"],["M1","1234"],["M2","5678"],["M1","1234"]]
df_clean = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values,columns=labels)
print(df_clean)
  Market  Code
0     M1  1234
1     M1  4567
2     M1  1234
3     M2  5678
4     M1  1234
```

Comment: Hi, what code have you tried? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.merge` on `Market` and `.loc` for subset of `df.Code == 'Dummy'` values

```
In [288]: df.loc[df.Code=='Dummy', 'Code'] = df.merge(df2, on='Market', how='left')['Code(New)']

In [289]: df
Out[289]:
  Market  Code
0     M1  1234
1     M1  4567
2     M1  1234
3     M2  5678
4     M1  1234
```

Comment: I have tried this code:
`index=["MKT_BUD","CUSTOMER"]`

`df.loc[df.CUSTOMER=='OTHEROE','CUSTOMER'] = df.merge(df2,how="inner",left_on=index,right_on=index)["New CUSTOMER"].values`

But the result is rather strange, it seems that it does not properly edit each line based on the right Market

Comment: I have created a dedicated topic for this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737332/use-df-merge-to-populate-a-new-column-in-df-gives-strange-matchs

Answer (score 2):

Base on your example

```
pd.concat([df1[df1.Code!='Dummy'],df2],axis=0)
```

You edited your input after I posted my answer, below is the solution with the updated input .

```
df2.columns=["Market","Code"]
df2.index=df[df.Code=='Dummy'].index
pd.concat([df[df.Code!='Dummy'],df2],axis=0).sort_index()


Out[372]: 
  Market  Code
0     M1  1234
1     M1  4567
2     M1  1234
3     M2  5678
4     M1  1234
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but would it work if you have in df multiple lines to be edited for the same market?

Comment: @Nicolas , If it is multiple line need to update under the same market , how to distinct the same Market name ?

Comment: No need to. This is just a part of a bigger scheme ;)