# Use df.merge to populate a new column in df gives strange matchs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

### I just found the 2 issues causing this, see solution below

I want to create a new column in my dataframe (df) based on another dataframe.
Basically df2 contains updated informations that I want to plug into df.
In order to replicate my real case (>1m lines), I will just populate two random df with simple columns.

I use pandas.merge() to do this, but this is giving me strange results.

Here is a typical example. Let's create df randomly and create df2 with a simple relationship : "New Type" = "Type" + 1. I create this simple relationship so that we can check easily the ouput. In my real application I don't have such an easy relationship of course.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)),columns = ["Type"])
df.head()

   Type
0    45
1     3
2    89
3     6
4    39

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Type":range(1,100)})
df1["New Type"] = df1["Type"] + 1
print(df1.head())

 Type  New Type
0     1         2
1     2         3
2     3         4
3     4         5
4     5         6
```

Now let's say I want to update df "Type" based on the "New Type" on df1

```
df["Type2"] = df.merge(df1,on="Type")["New Type"]
print(df.head())
```

I get this strange output where we clearly see that it does not work

```
  Type  Type2
0    45   46.0
1     3    4.0
2    89    4.0
3     6    4.0
4    39   90.0
```

I would think output should be like

```
  Type  Type2
0    45   46.0
1     3    4.0
2    89   90.0
3     6    7.0
4    39   40.0
```

Only the first line is properly matched. Do you know what I've missed?

### Solution

1.I need to do merge with how="left" otherwise the default choice is "inner" producing another table with a different dimension than df.

2. Also I need to use sort=false as attribute to my merge function. Otherwise the merge result is sorted before being applied to df.

Comment: What do you want the output be like?

Comment: I've added this thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this using `map`, `set_index`, and `squeeze`:

```
df['Type2'] = df['Type'].map(df1.set_index('Type').squeeze())
```

Output:

```
   Type  Type2
0    22   23.0
1    56   57.0
2    63   64.0
3    33   34.0
4    25   26.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd construct a Series of `New Type` indexed by the old `Type` from `df1`:

```
new_vals = df1.set_index('Type')['New Type']
```

Then it's simply:

```
df.replace(new_vals)
```

That will leave values which aren't mapped intact.  If you want to instead have the output be `NaN` (null) where not mapped, do this:

```
new_vals[df.Type]
```