# Replace values from one column by comparing another column to a second DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, lookup-tables

I'm trying to replace *NaN* values from the `air_store_id` column of the `df` DataFrame using a particular criteria that involves searching into another DataFrame:

```
data = { 'air_store_id':     [ 'air_a1',   np.nan, 'air_a3',   np.nan,  'air_a5' ], 
         'hpg_store_id':     [ 'hpg_a1', 'hpg_a2',   np.nan, 'hpg_a4',    np.nan ],
                 'Test':     [ 'Alpha',    'Beta',  'Gamma',  'Delta', 'Epsilon' ]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df)
```

[image]

When a NaN is found in `df.air_store_id` I would like to use the value from `df.hpg_store_id` (when there is one) to compare it to the same column in another DataFrame called `id_table_df`, and retrieve its `air_store_id`.

Here is what `id_table_df` looks like:

```
ids_data = { 'air_store_id':     [ 'air_a1', 'air_a4', 'air_a3', 'air_a2' ], 
             'hpg_store_id':     [ 'hpg_a1', 'hpg_a4', 'hpg_a3', 'hpg_a2' ] }

id_table_df = pd.DataFrame(ids_data)
display(id_table_df)
```

[image]

Simply put, for every *NaN* in `df.air_store_id` replace it for the appropriate equivalent in `id_table_df.air_store_id` by comparing `df.hpg_store_id` with `id_table_df.hpg_store_id`.

In this scenario, `id_table_df` ends up working as a *lookup table*. The resulting DataFrame would look like this:

[image]

I've [tried to merge them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45677050/176769) with the following instruction, but an error is thrown:

```
df.loc[df.air_store_id.isnull(), 'air_store_id'] = df.merge(id_table_df, on='hpg_store_id', how='left')['air_store_id']
```

Error message:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2441             try:
-> 2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2443             except KeyError:
...
...
...
KeyError: 'air_store_id'
```

**Question 1:** how can I accomplish?

**Question 2:** is there a way to do this at simultaneously for both columns (`air_store_id` and `hpg_store_id`)? If it were possible I wouldn't have to run the merge separately for each column.

Comment: That won't work @MaxU.  The index values aren't aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `pd.Series.map` after using `set_index` on `id_table_df`

```
df.fillna(
    df.hpg_store_id.map(
        id_table_df.set_index('hpg_store_id').air_store_id
    ).to_frame('air_store_id')
)

      Test air_store_id hpg_store_id
0    Alpha       air_a1       hpg_a1
1     Beta       air_a2       hpg_a2
2    Gamma       air_a3          NaN
3    Delta       air_a4       hpg_a4
4  Epsilon       air_a5          NaN
```

---

Simultaneously

```
v = id_table_df.values
a2h = dict(v)
h2a = dict(v[:, ::-1])
df.fillna(
    pd.concat([
        df.hpg_store_id.map(h2a),
        df.air_store_id.map(a2h),
    ], axis=1, keys=['air_store_id', 'hpg_store_id'])
)

      Test air_store_id hpg_store_id
0    Alpha       air_a1       hpg_a1
1     Beta       air_a2       hpg_a2
2    Gamma       air_a3       hpg_a3
3    Delta       air_a4       hpg_a4
4  Epsilon       air_a5          NaN
```

---

**Creative Solution**
requires Python 3

```
v = id_table_df.values
a2h = dict(v)
h2a = dict(v[:, ::-1])
col = id_table_df.columns
swch = dict(zip(col, col[::-1]))
df.fillna(df.applymap({**a2h, **h2a}.get).rename(columns=swch))

      Test air_store_id hpg_store_id
0    Alpha       air_a1       hpg_a1
1     Beta       air_a2       hpg_a2
2    Gamma       air_a3       hpg_a3
3    Delta       air_a4       hpg_a4
4  Epsilon       air_a5         None
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting! Sounds like I should investigate `map()` further.

Comment: There is more to explore after that as well (-: